# How to change a label of another page using hyperlink?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I'd like to ask if it is possible to change a page's label using a hyperlink from another page.

I want to pass a value, ex. '1' and use it as a label for another template. I am able to redirect from page to page using hyperlink but I have no idea how to pass some parameters to be used by another.

The Hyperlink's purpose is to tell the other page that it is for a certain value.

Here's the code of my hyperlink:

```
//It is a hyperlink with image.
<a class="btn bgImg"  href="{% url 'trend_view'%}"></a>
```

Here's the code in my view:

```
def stage_trend_view(request, value):
    args={ val = value}
    template = loader.get_template("Hole_Analyzer/trend_per_stage.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render(args, request))
```

And here's the template I want to use the value being passed:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Stages{% endblock %}
{% block content-nav %} {% endblock content-nav %}

{% block card_title %}Trend for Stage {{val}} {% endblock card_title %}
    {% block content-Card %}
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <p>This is Graphs and shits</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endblock content-Card %}
{% block scripts %} {% endblock scripts %}
```

Here's the url.py:

```
path(r'^trend/(?P<value>\d+)/$', stage_trend_view, name='trend_view')
```

Comment: Is your question about how to add GET parameters in url? `http://localhost.com/page?data=1`

Comment: @Pax yes, but also how to send that parameter using a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll mention 2 ways for GET request to do this.

### One way is to add it as a value in url:

Hyperlink code as same:

```
<a class="btn bgImg"  href="{% url 'trend_view' value/variable_here %}"></a>
```

In code view.py:

```
from django.template import Context
def stage_trend_view(request, value):
    args=Context({"val" : value})
    template = loader.get_template("Hole_Analyzer/trend_per_stage.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render(args))
```

in urls.py:

```
path('trend/<int:value>/', stage_trend_view, name='trend_view')
```

### Another way is to set it as GET parameter

Hyperlink code as:

```
<a class="btn bgImg"  href="{% url 'trend_view' %}?value={{value/vairable_here}}"></a>
```

In code views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def stage_trend_view(request):
    value = request.GET.get('value')
    return render(request, 'Hole_Analyzer/trend_per_stage.html', {'val':value})
```

In urls.py:

```
path('trend/', stage_trend_view, name='trend_view')
```

You are free to chose one suitable for you :)

Comment: TY for this. Solved my problem using the first solution.